# Siril appimage returns Glib-GIO-Error .. missing antialiasing key ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wayland

When trying to run the siril astrophotography stacking software from the version 1.0.2 appimage file this error shows up.

(siril:882824): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 08:30:09.016: Settings schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings' does not contain a key named 'antialiasing'
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

I renamed the siril.appimage file to siril, changed file permissions and ran with ./siril. This process works for other software .. for example the 3d printer slicer cura.

Is there a way around this. Some have suggested it is because siril uses x11 rather than wayland. Not sure if there is truth to that.

This appimage runs in a debian window on a Google Chrome laptop.

Any suggestions on getting this to run under Ubuntu? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the problem is with Wayland.
The only way I can get it to work is to log into Ubuntu by selecting "Ubuntu on X11" from the login screen. Then it works fine.
It's annoying but at least it will run this way.